# Context Manager implemented inside class errors as "instance has no attribute '__exit__'"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to learn about context manager in python as explained here: http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html

I have a slight variation where I am returning an instance from a class method. The object has __enter__ and __exit__ methods defined as suggested in the tutorial.

```
class Response():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.headers = {'Connection': 'dummy'}
        self.body = 'testtest'
        print('SingleRequest()')

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        pass

    def test():
        print('This is test')

class Fetcher():
    def __init__(self):
    print('Fetcher()')

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
    pass

def get(self, url):
    print ('Fetcher()::get()')
    return Response(url)

def verify():
    with Fetcher() as session:
        with session.get("https://www.google.com/") as response:
            response.test()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    verify()
```

I get the following error even though __exit__ is defined in Response.

```
AttributeError: Response instance has no attribute '__exit__'
```

Comment: There are some indentation problems with your question that make it hard to tell if you have a real problem or if you just need to fix your indentation. If the indentation is just a copy/paste issue, you'll want to fix it so people can focus on other aspects of your code.

Comment: Your indentation is off. `Fetcher` indeed does not have `__exit__` in its class body from what you posted.

Comment: It was an indentation issue. Thank you for pointing out.